# write system call stops at nul

Tags: unix, system-calls

Well it may be obvious to some but not to me (and it is not mentioned in the documentation) :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char s[]= {'h','\0','l','0'};
    int fd=open("myfile.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND,0644);
    write(fd,s,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Will only write 'h' to the file - so a nul in the buffer terminates write() despite being asked to write past it ? How do I write a nul to a file then ?

Thanks !

Comment: when i run your code, it right H10 to the file, so its not stopping on `\0`, this is on ubuntu natty

Comment: how are you making sure that the data is not there? are you on windows?

Comment: I tried this on an older ubuntu version - no this wont run on windows. I open the file and only see an H in it . So you think it may be system dependent ?

Comment: how did you check the file contents?

Comment: Side note: you're calling `open` with the `O_CREAT` flag, but you don't give a `mode` argument. That means the file's permissions are undefined.

Comment: @larsmans : corrected - @ osgx : I open the file with an editor - hm now I tried pico and it shows h^@10 so it was an editor thing ! Thanks everybody :)

Comment: If you have an answer, then post it as one, don't modify the question.

Comment: @skaffman : why so ? Moreover : _New users can't answer their own question for 8 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead_

Comment: @Mr: Because that's how this works. It's to discourage people posting frivolous questions that they answer themselves straight after asking.

Comment: @skaffman : anyway the Stack advised me to _edit your question instead_ (and won't let me answer). Moreover I did research and it was osgx who pointed me to the right direction - would you check a file with a couple of txt editors lest the first one you used had a bug ? It wouldn't occur to me, sorry. Finally the behavior of write is still not clear to me - would it write a nul to a FIFO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : pico shows h^@10 - so the nul got written after all - so it was "WinSCP's Internal Text Editor". Still something of a mystery to me.

(answered as prompted in the comments - still if someone could confirm this for me so I can be 100% sure...)